# Windows 11 Change username for Azure AD account

Tags: windows-11, azure-activedirectory

My Windows 11 PC is setup with my Azure AD account. But the username contains a single quote. This messes up some software/scripts because it's also included in my user folder.
Is there a way to change this? Preferably without having to reinstall everything.

My last name does include the single quote so it's in my actual name. But it's not really a good idea to have it in my Windows username. Any hints on how to fix this are welcome.

Comment: Your Azure Administrator can change the username of your account, without changing your name associated with the account, not having a single quote is like having a number after your last name. Your username does not have to match your name exactly. The only way to change the profile directory name is as an administrator

Comment: Where can we find the username property?